# How do you finish carpet on the landing at the top of a hardwood staircase?

Tags: carpet, stairs

If I'm installing hardwood treads and risers and removing carpet from the stairs, what do you do with the top or landing if you have carpet on there now? Would you just have the carpet wrap over top to meet last riser?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the carpet to meet the final riser, or you can install a landing tread.

It completely depends on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the carpet like you suggested. You can have the carpet held back some in an arc from the top tread and fill in with a bit more hardwood. Or you can purge all the upper level carpet and install a hardwood floor there too.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the carpet over the top is how I've always seen it done. That avoids any risk of an irregularity, and thus a trip hazard, at that edge.

Though personally I'd consider removing the carpet from the landing etc. too, unless you have a specific reason to want it there. I've become very fond of wood floors with area rugs in selected places rather than wall-to-wall; easier to maintain, I like the look better, and if you wear slippers there's virtually no difference to your feet.